# How do enable/disable or show/hide SharedPreferences in programs

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

It seems like it should be very simple to enable/disable and show/hide Preferences from within the Android program. But I can't get it to work other than directly within the XML file itself. I've only been able to find tutorials and example for deprecated preferences. Here is an example that I'm trying to get to work for hiding and disabling to two preferences below.

```
root_preferences.xml

<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Preference
        android:key="hidePref"
        app:title="Hide/Show"
        app:summary="Change this preference's visibility"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="disablePref"
        app:title="Enable/Disable"
        app:summary="Enable or Disable this preference"/>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

```
MainActivity.kt

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val sharedPreferences = Preferencemanager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

    //No idea how to do the following but here are guess that obviously do not work
    sharedPreferences.edit().isVisible("hidePref", View.GONE).apply()
    sharedPreferences.edit().isEnabled("disabledPref", false).apply()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` and `Preference` are two very distinct classes. A `SharedPreferences` is a singleton object that lets you interact with the properties file that holds your map of preferences data. A `Preference` is a view widget that lets the user directly modify `SharedPreferences`.

What you're describing you want to do is to modify visibility or enabled state of the view widget `Preference`s. This will not involve `SharedPreferences` at all.

Presumably you have your preference views on screen in a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` as the [documentation explains](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings?hl=en). To modify a specific `Preference` view, you use `findPreference()` in your fragment. You can specify a more specific type than `Preference` if necessary (so long as it matches the type of the actual preference in your XML that you're looking up).

The return type is nullable because it returns null if it doesn't find it. You look up the preference using its key. So, to do what your posted code seems to be intended to do, you could put:

```
class MySettingsFragment: PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, null)

        findPreference<Preference>("hidepref")?.isVisible = false
        findPreference<Preference>("disabledPref")?.isEnabled = false
    }

}
```

I personally choose to put all my preference keys in a string resources file (and use `tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"` in that file to keep the linter from complaining). That way the literal strings of the keys are only typed in one place, reducing error. I write helper functions for getting these preference values from `SharedPreferences` or finding the `Preference` views using the resource ID.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Tenfour04. Follow up question, is there a way to see which Activity the user was on when they initiated the button click to load the preferences? For instance I have Activity A and Activity B and the flow goes from A to B. I have a Preference that I only want usable when user is at Activity B, but disabled if they entered Preferences while on Activity A. The only solution I can think of is to have different sets of preference xml files for each Activity which could get messing trying to copy the pref values between them.

Comment: Your settings fragment can check which Activity it’s attached after it’s attached and hide specific Preferences accordingly.